# jQuery change label and icon alignment?

Tags: jquery, css

For jQuery checkbox and label, the default alignment is like:

```
[x] label
```

How can I change them, so that label is in front? Using firebug I did not find any alignment statments on them.

Comment: "Default alignment" is dictated by the document order of elements and text direction, I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply place the label text before the `<input type = "checkbox"/>` so you code looks like this:

```
<label for = "testCheckbox">Label</label> <input type = "checkbox" id = "testCheckbox" name = "testCheckBox"/>
```

Comment: Or simply `<label>Label <input type="checkbox" name="testCheckBox" /></label>` if the two are adjacent.